# Apps Script script in Google Sheets moving the wrong row with two onEdit triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using 2 functions in a tracker that I have. 1 function is for sorting column C by date (earliest first) automatically when a cell in that column is edited. If the word 'done' or 'void' is typed into that cell then the entire row is copied onto the next sheet.

However my issue is that when I type 'done' or 'void' into this cell, Google sheets is sorting the list and also processing the move function and thus moving the wrong row (the resulting row number, after the sort). How can i fix or improve the code.

```
function movedonevoid(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var value = r.getValue();

  if(s.getName() == "tracker" && r.getColumn() == 3 && (value=="done" || value=="void" )) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("tracker2");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

and

```
function sorttracker(event){

  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(sheet.getName() == 'tracker'){
    var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

    var columnToSortBy = 3;
    var tableRange = "A2:D"; // What to sort.

    if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy) {   
      var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
      range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
    }
  }
}
```

I've inserted the above 2 bits of code as 2 different scripts and then used project triggers for both 'on edit'. Not sure if that is the best approach?

Comment: I would not use two "on edit" triggers.  Check the conditions, and branch to another function if need be.  I haven't tested whether two "on edit" triggers will both fire, but I'm assuming that is what you have experienced.  Do you know which one fires first?  Do they always run in the same order?  It's probably not necessarily bad to have two functions running asynchronously, as long as the data from one doesn't depend on data changed by the other.

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed, having two different functions acting over the same range and being called by two different onEdit triggers isn't a good idea.

Instead of using two onEdit triggers, use only one to call an [orchestral conductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conducting) function that will call the original two. The `orchestral conductor function` could be something like the following:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   movedonevoid(e);
   sorttracker(e);
}
```